# Weshalb werden manche Wörter mit Doppelvokal gedehnt („aa“, „ee“, …)?

Tags: spelling

Ich habe vor kurzem gelesen, dass das deutsche Wort *Waage* erst seit 1927 offiziell mit Doppel-a geschrieben wird (Zitat aus dem Duden von 1929):

> Durch eine Bekanntmachung des Reichsministers des Innern vom 5. Juli 1927 (Reichsministerialblatt 1927, Nr. 29, S. 205) wurde, einer Anregung der Technik entsprechend, die Schreibung *Waage* (an Stelle von bisherigem *"Wage"*) zur besseren Unterscheidung vom *"Wagen"* in die amtliche Rechtschreibung aufgenommen.

Diese Änderung lässt sich mithilfe des [Google Ngram Viewers schön visualisieren](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Waage,Wage&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3):

[image: Waage vs. wage Ngram Viewer]

Ich habe nun versucht, ein paar weitere Beispiele zu finden. Dabei ist mir aufgefallen, dass es im Deutschen das *o* nur selten mit einem Doppelvokal gedehnt wird („Moor“), und der Buchstabe meines Wissens *u* überhaupt nicht verdoppelt wird. Das lange *i* existiert als Diphthong *ie*. Die Buchstaben *a* und *e* sind relativ häufig als Doppelvokale anzutreffen.

*Nun meine Frage:* **Warum werden manche Wörter mit Doppelvokal gedehnt, andere hingegen nicht oder mit einem *stummen h?* Und warum ist die Verteilung für die einzelnen Vokale so unterschiedlich?**

Comment: Gute Frage! Hier noch ein Beispiel zur Illustration: fahren, garen, haaren.

Comment: Das *U* wird, zugegeben selten, mit einem *E* gedehnt. So wird z.B. der Firmenname *Huek* als *Huuk* ausgesprochen und nicht *Hük*.

Comment: @Markus: Außer bei Eigennamen (und dort eher regional, vermute ich - ich kenne kein Beispiel) ist das aber in Deutsch nicht die Regel. Das "u" ist prinzipiell lang, wenn kein Doppelkonsonant folgt: *gut* / *dumm*

Comment: Gute Frage - nächste Frage.  :)
(Ich würde jetzt mal die Hypothese aufstellen, dass Doppelvokale in erster Linie etymologische und homonymunterscheidende Funktion haben, aber ich kann das nicht begründen.)

Comment: +1 für den wunderbar treffsicheren Einsatz des Google toys :-). Und Gegenfrage: Ab wann wird Google nur noch mit einem "o" geschrieben werden?

Comment: @splattne Hast du Zahlen für die Verteilung der nach der grandiosen Antwort verbiebenen Doppelvokale *aa*, *ee* und *oo*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Der Grund, warum die Verdoppelung bei bestimmten Vokalbuchstaben nicht auftritt, hat graphische oder historische Gründe:

1. Der Buchstabe *i* wird nicht verdoppelt, weil ein verdoppeltes *ıı* von einem *u* bzw. – mit Punkten – ein verdoppeltes *ii* von einem *ü* kaum zu unterscheiden ist. Dies gilt insbsondere in der Handschrift, und insbesondere in gebrochenen Schriften wie der [deutschen Kurrentschrift](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Kurrentschrift) – vgl. auch [minim (paleography)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minim_(palaeography)).
2. Der Buchstabe *u* wird nicht verdoppelt, weil das Deutsche historisch gesehen bereits ein verdoppeltes *uu* hat, nämlich den Buchstaben *w.* Das doppelte *uu* wurde (im Frühmittelalter?) zur Verschriftlichung des germanischen Lauts [w] erfunden, den es im Latein nicht mehr gab. Erst in der Neuzeit wurde das doppelte *uu* zu einem eigenständigen Buchstaben, dem *w.* Die Herkunft als doppeltes *uu* zeigt sich z.B. noch im englischen Namen “double u”.
3. Die Buchstaben *ä, ö* und *ü* werden im Deutschen nicht verdoppelt, weil es sich historisch gesehen bereits um Doppelbuchstaben handelt, nämlich *ae, oe* und *ue.* Lange habe ich übrigens selber nicht gewusst, dass dies für den Umlaut von *aa* und *oo* noch immer gilt. So wird «Haar» mit Umlaut zu «Härchen», «Boot» zu «Bötlein» usw. (vgl. amtl. Regelwerk [§9 E2](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6174#par9)).

Verdoppelbar sind also nur die Buchstaben *a, e* und *o.* Dass doppeltes *oo* seltener auftritt als doppeltes *aa* oder *ee,* könnte damit zu tun, das der entspr. Laut – langes /oː/ – wohl seltener ist als langes /aː/ oder /eː/. Vielleicht ist es auch eher ein Zufall, denn insgesamt ist die Verdoppelung von Vokalbuchstaben im Deutschen eher selten anzutreffen.

Exkurs: Im Niederländischen sowie im Alemannischen verbreitete sich (im Spätmittelalter/in der frühen Neuzeit?) ein doppeltes *ii* für das lange /iː/. Zur besseren Unterscheidung wurde das zweite *i* jedoch lang geschrieben, also als *j,* das damals noch kein eigener Buchstabe, sondern bloss eine Nebenform des *i* war. Also schrieb man *ij.* Als nach Einführung des Buchdrucks dieses *ij* einer Drucktype zugeordnet werden sollte, wählte man im Alemannischen das ähnlich aussehende *y* (im Afrikaans *ÿ).* Im Niederländischen änderte sich (ähnlich wie im Deutschen) die Aussprache des ursprünglichen langen /iː/ zu /ɛi/. Also gehen Schreibungen wie niederländisch *snijder/tijd* oder alemannisch *Schnyder/Zyt,* die hochdeutschem *Schneider/Zeit* entsprechen, auf ein doppeltes *ii* zurück. Ebenso verhält es sich auch bei *Schwyz,* das hochdeutschem *Schweiz* entspricht, nur hat sich hier eine orthografische Unterscheidung eingebürgert, wonach die Schreibung *Schwyz* nur noch für Stadt und Kanton, *Schweiz* hingegen für das Land verwendet wird, obwohl sie im Schweizerdeutschen genau gleich ausgesprochen werden, nämlich /ˈʃʋiːts/.

Comment: Vermutlich kommt daher auch das ÿ?

Comment: Genau. Im Alltag werden im Niederländischen ÿ und y oft wie Varianten von ij behandelt, vgl. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/IJ#Gleichstellung_mit_dem_Y . Anekdote: Ich kenne jemanden mit alemannischem y im Nachnamen (so etwas wie «Schnyder»). Auf dem niederländischen Personalausweis wurde ein ij daraus, zunächst ein Ärgernis, bis ich erklären konnte, dass es ja schrifthistorisch völlig gerechtfertigt ist (wenn auch nicht fürs moderne Alphabet).

Comment: Was für eine ergiebige Lektüre! Bist du vom Fach?

Answer (score 2):

These sites show, **how** *Diphthongierung* evolved historically and geographically

http://de.inforapid.org/index.php5?search=Diphthongierung

http://apuzik.deutschesprache.ru/lektion-8.html

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nat%C3%BCrlichkeitstheorie

http://www.zeno.org/Meyers-1905/A/Deutsche+Sprache

http://www.archive.org/stream/diedeutschespra00feisgoog/diedeutschespra00feisgoog_djvu.txt

http://www.grin.com/de/e-book/127435/die-entwicklung-der-spanischen-diphthongierung-anhand-der-natuerlichkeitstheorie

There seem to be lots of articles about development of *Diphthongierung*, but **no reasons are listed why** it developed.

**Why Doppelvokale aa ee are more common:**

My intuition as hobby musician is that it has **partly** to do with singing. Long held aa ee just sound common and can fit in many points of a song while a long held oo uu ii sounds not so common/nice and is physically harder to sing. The pitch of aa and ee is nearer to "average" pitch of human voice. Have you ever heard babies singing/screaming long oo uu ii, we are physically not used to this pitches. Imo above *Natürlichkeitstheorie* would also suggest this reasoning. German has many dialects, so strong influence by local culture/music was likely always a major factor too. *Diphthongierung* was also a localized phenomenon according to above links.